# Windows VM with vSphere - not accessible

Tags: windows, vmware-esxi, vnc, vsphere-client

I have multiple ESXi hosts that were being managed by vSphere clients running on Windows VM on one of the host itself. Accidently I changed the setting of VNC to be read only and eventually due to some memory issues, had to restart that Windows VM from command prompt of ESXi host that was hosting it.

Issue is that since VNC was in read only mode, I cannot log into that machine and restart vSphere clients. What are my options - is it really kaput scenario? Can I install vSphere client on other box and add inventory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to worry.  All you have to do is go to another computer that has a connection to your hosts/hosts network, and open your web browser and navigate to the IP address of one of your ESXi hosts.  Once you've done that, you'll be presented with a screen that looks like this:

[image]

Download vSphere Client by using the download link found there.  There is nothing tied to any install of vSphere Client in anyway like a finger print or GUID, etc, so you won't hurt anything installing vSphere Client on multiple computers.  Install vSphere Client and then connect like you always do using the IP(s) of the host(s) and the correct username/password combo.  You can do this from any computer with a connection to your hosts.

Comment: Update on this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the vSphere console to access the VM's from another machine?

This link should help downloading the client - https://superuser.com/questions/439356/where-can-i-find-the-vmware-vsphere-client

Comment: I was going to do that now ... question is that multiple vSphere conosles - are the allowed ? Does host register any console - then it will be waste. Also does the console store any local files ? But I am going to try anyway

Comment: Yeah - providing you supply it the correct username / password. Not sure what you mean by "Does host register any console". Not that I'm aware of at least nothing important - it's literally like a client frontend to the esx(i) boxes

Comment: I meant by registering, host might maintain finger print of the machine where console is hosted for security reasons... Will update thread tonight after the experiment. Thanks

Comment: Nope - I believe the only fingerprinting is done is by the client to authenticate and transmit/receive the hosts identity/data via SSL certificates